# Javascript - Select div element by its class name and add an image in it

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

```js
let output = document.getElementsByClassName("one");

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4581a99fa5793feaeff38d989a1524c6?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG";
img.width = "25px";
document.output[0].appendChild(img);
```

```css
.one {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Test</div>
```

The above code gives an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`...

Comment: What makes you think that `output` is the same as `document.output`? Why would these two be related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reference `output[0]`, not `document.output[0]`.

Also, you need to set the image `width=""` attribute to `25`, not `25px`.

```js
let output = document.getElementsByClassName("one");

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4581a99fa5793feaeff38d989a1524c6?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG";
img.width = "25";
output[0].appendChild(img);
```

```css
.one {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Test</div>
```